# Canvas resizing without changing width of path in Paper.js

Tags: canvas, path, resize, width, paperjs

I'm trying to get effect, when canvas is resizing but a path drawn on it still has the same width. However it changes width proportional to canvas width. I tried to repaint path, however a paper object seems to remember old width and height and scales path despite of my new settings applied to path.
Maybe the solution is to scale width of path, however I hope there's a more gently solution.

---

ANSWER
It seems the best solution is to scaling width and radius of path and shapes. When you draw a new path after resizing, you have to pass old width and height to new point coordinates.
Maybe this is not a gently solution but works and I don't see another one.

Comment: I have also problem with the position of path. It seems canvas after resisizing to small hava a much bigger resolution.... and my path changes position not to the same relative position to image.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell your canvas to resize automatically, see here:

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/#canvas-configuration

Then it change its size, but it shouldn't scale the content along. You can see this in action in all examples on the paper.js website, e.g. http://paperjs.org/examples/rounded-rectangles/

The ones that scale along are programmatically told to do so.

If you just scale the canvas object the CSS way, then you'll end up with blown up pixels and wrong offsets in mouse events.

If you don't want to use the resize attribute, but still need to resize the canvas, you can do so by calling `paper.view.setViewSize(width, height)` and it will do the resizing for you, respecting HiDPI settings and all.

Answer (score 2):

I may be a little late to the party, but I had the same issue recently and I solved it by adding the `resize` attribute on the `canvas` element.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true"></canvas>
```

Don't forget to *explicitly* set `resize` to equal `true` (i.e. `resize="true"`).

Simply having the resize attribute present, or with any other value wont do it.